# What is wrong with my dsfont package?

Tags: fonts

I have never had problems with the package `dsfont` before. But suddenly in all my documents (independent of the combination of `\usepackage`s in the preamble) the dsfonts look very poor in the PDF. They have bad quality and look pixelated. I have no idea what happened here. Also the minimal working example below gives me a PDF that looks awful.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\begin{document}
\[\mathds{N}=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}\]
\[\mathds{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
C:\Users\cala>updmap --verbose
Parsing config file "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\config\updmap.cfg"...
Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\tetex\dvips35.map"...
Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\tetex\pdftex35.map"...
Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\tetex\dvipdfm35.map"...
Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\tetex\ps2pk35.map"...
Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\amsfonts\cm.map"...
Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\amsfonts\cmextra.map"...
Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\amsfonts\cyrillic.map"...
Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\amsfonts\euler.map"...
Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\dvips\eurosym\eurosym.map"...
Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\amsfonts\latxfont.map"...
Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\mflogo-font\mflogo.map"...
Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\rsfs\rsfs.map"...
Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\amsfonts\symbols.map"...
Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\xypic\xypic.map"...
Parsing C:\Users\cala\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\map\dvips\arabi\arabi.map...
Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\psnfss\charter.map"...
Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\psnfss\fpls.map"...
Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\lm\lm.map"...
Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\psnfss\pazo.map"...
Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\pslatex\pcrr8rn.map"...
Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\psnfss\psnfss.map"...
Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\avantgar\uag.map"...
Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\bookman\ubk.map"...
Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\courier\ucr.map"...
Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\helvetic\uhv.map"...
Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\ncntrsbk\unc.map"...
Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\palatino\upl.map"...
Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\times\utm.map"...
Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\psnfss\utopia.map"...
Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\zapfchan\uzc.map"...
Parsing "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\zapfding\uzd.map"...
Writing C:\Users\cala\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\dvips\config\ps2pk.map...
Writing C:\Users\cala\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\dvips\config\download35.map...
Writing C:\Users\cala\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\dvips\config\builtin35.map...
Writing C:\Users\cala\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\dvips\config\psfonts_t1.map...
Writing C:\Users\cala\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\dvips\config\psfonts_pk.map...
Writing C:\Users\cala\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\pdftex\config\pdftex_ndl14.map...
Writing C:\Users\cala\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\pdftex\config\pdftex_dl14.map...
Writing C:\Users\cala\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\dvipdfm\config\dvipdfm_dl14.map...
Writing C:\Users\cala\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\dvipdfm\config\dvipdfm_ndl14.map...
Copying C:\Users\cala\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\dvips\config\psfonts_t1.map
to C:\Users\cala\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\dvips\config\psfonts.map...
Copying C:\Users\cala\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\dvipdfm\config\dvipdfm_dl14.map
to C:\Users\cala\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\dvipdfm\config\dvipdfm.map...
Copying C:\Users\cala\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\pdftex\config\pdftex_dl14.map
to C:\Users\cala\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\pdftex\config\pdftex.map...
C:\Users\cala>updmap
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: I am using MiKTeX (and Texmaker).

Comment: Check first Ulrike's answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108447/how-should-one-maintain-and-update-a-miktex-installation

Comment: Look in the log file. At the end here should be something similar to `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/doublestroke/dsrom10.pfb` mentioned in it. This is a Type 1 font. I guess it couldn't find that and reverted to some bitmap font.

Comment: I have ``\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\public\doublestroke\dpi600\dsrom10.pk``.

Comment: @egreg I already reinstalled the doublestroke package.

Comment: @user144697 Then probably the `updmap` passage is missing

Comment: Very often, MiKTeX doesn't run  `updmap` after installing a type 1 font, so that it tries to make bitmaps.

Comment: So what should I do now?

Comment: Run `updmap` from the command line (as administrator) to refresh the psfonts database. If you add `--verbose`, you'll read what happens.

Comment: Ok, I did this and saw that some stuff happened at the command line, but my problem remains the same.

Comment: I also uninstalled MiKTeX and reinstalled it, but the dsfonts still look ugly.

Comment: What does `kpsewhich dsrom10.pfb` give?

Comment: @cfr Thank you for your suggestion.  I tried it but the problem still is here.

Comment: More precisely, I see something like `/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/doublestroke/dsrom10.pfb`.

Comment: So it really looks like a classic `updmap` problem. Try the `updmap` instructions again and post the output in your question.

Comment: @cfr As suggested from you, I did the instructions again and posted the output in the question.

Comment: Didn't @Bernard say you needed to do this as administrator? I don't know enough about Windows/MikTeX to be sure, but isn't that output from a run as an ordinary user? It isn't adding `dstroke.map` at any rate, which is why it isn't making any difference. Does `kpsewhich dstroke.map` return a valid path?

Comment: Yes, I did it as an administrator also, but now - just for copying the output - I forgot about it.

Comment: I just get
`C:\Windows\system32>kpsewhich dstroke.map`
`C:\Windows\system32>`
but no path is returned?

Comment: So we see that `kpsewhich dsrom10.pfb` returns some path but unfortunately `kpsewhich dstroke.map` doesn't.

Comment: @cfr: It returns nothing.  The problem comes from %iKTeX packaging: `dstroke.map` is not in the right place.

Comment: @Bernard Aha - a bug :(.

Comment: Is this my fault or the package's fault or ...? As mentioned before, I already uninstalled MikTex together with all packages, but this did not help. What should I do now?

Comment: It's MiKTeX fault: it's installed in an old location. Nowadays, all .map files have to be in the `fonts\map` directory. Please see details in my answer.

Comment: @cfr: I think Christian Schenk forgot to change the old location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem comes from a wrong installation of `dstroke.map`:
it is installed in `MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\dvips\doublestroke`, and it it should be in `MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\doublestroke`.

*Solution:* move the whole directory `doublestroke\` to the correct place `MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\map\dvips\`. Then launch `MiKTeX Settings to refresh the FNDB, and run`updmap` (as Administrator).

Here is what I obtained afterwards:

[image]

Comment: It is fine now, I am so glad about it, thank you very much! I spent so much time with this problem, thought my combination of usepackages is bad at first ...
But I wonder why nowhere else is reported about this problem. Maybe it has something to do with the "November package refactoring" of MikTex?

Comment: I would like to give you 100+ upvotes but unfortunatley I can not even give you a single one as I have to less reputation.

Comment: I don't think so. Refactoring has to see with essential packages. Simply, it uses the old loaction for map files (more than 10years old, I guess). No one reported it probably because it's not widely used, and many people don't even know where to report. In any case, I couldn't have reported, baecause I prefer to use old style *Bourbaki*'s convention of real boldface for numbers sets.

Comment: @user144697: That's really unimportant. It's a pleasure to feel helpful!

Comment: Yes, this was extremely helpful and I really admire how you discovered the origin of the problem.

Anyway, I always try to create "nice" LaTeX files with good notation and I was never happy with `\mathbb{N,Q,R}` (although I have the feeling that its use is wide-spread) so I changed to `\mathds{N,Q,R}`. Now you made me curious about Bourbaki's convention, do you just use `\mathbf{N,Q,R}`?

Comment: Exactly. I'm very old-style;o). Just a detail puzzles me: even your commas are double-stroked?

Comment: Of course not, just was not concentrated when writing commas inside...